# Require to global scope in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my node.js script I have:

```
var wu = require('./wu-0.1.8.js');
```

just to play with **wu**.

If it was in browser, then I could just use `wu` everywhere e.g.

```
wu([1,2,3]).map( function(n){ return n*n; } );
```

Hovever in node.js I have to write:

```
wu.wu([1,2,3]).map( function(n){ return n*n; } );
```

Is it possible to *append* `wu` to global scope so that I dont have to type `wu.wu` all the time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var wu = require('./wu-0.1.8.js').wu;
```

**edit (response to comments):**

If you need to use other methods in `require('./wu-0.1.8.js')`, you can always do this...

```
var wuModule = require('./wu-0.1.8.js'); 
var wu = wuModule.wu;

// Now you can do 

wu([1,2,3]).map( function(n){ return n*n; } );
wuModule.someOtherWuMethod(...);
```

Comment: what if there were more exported functions that I wanted to access, say 100 ?

Comment: you mean like, wu.foo(), wu.bar(), in addition to wu.wu()?

Comment: Then my answer would not work... but it wouldn't make sense for there to be a wu.wu method at all if it's a "master" function (like $ is in jQuery). The designer(s) of wu should have exported the wu function and added wu.foo and wu.bar as methods (properties of wu).

Answer (score 3):

Well, I suggest you not to do so but you can iterate through the `wu` object properties and attach them to global object:

```
var _wu = require('./wu-0.1.8.js');
var key;
for (key in _wu) {
  if (_wu.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    global[key] = _wu[key];
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool... but so broken!

Comment: @wprl what is so broken?